# How do I test a function that calls another function in jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a function that converts an array of 8 bit integers into a x-bit integer. This function has extensive unit tests in Jest. This function is called `convertArrayIntoInt()`.

I have another functions that relies on `convertArrayIntoInt()` called `getSignature()`.

```js
/**
 * @param {Uint8Array} fileContents The file contents
 * @param {number} position The position in the file where the signature is.
 * @return {number} the 32 bit signature
 */
function getSignature(fileContents, position) {
    let signature = fileContents.slice(position, position + 4);
    signature = convertArrayIntoInt(signature);
    for(let s in Enums.Signatures) {
        if(signature === parseInt(s)) {
            return signature;
        }
    }
    return Enums.Signatures.BAD_SIGNATURE;
}
```

I want to write a test for this function that tests whether `Uint8Array.of(0x04, 0x03, 0x4b, 0x50), 0)` returns `0x04034b50` or `Enums.BAD_SIGNATURE`. I heard that with unit testing, you don't want to test a function that relies on the output of another function. How do I go about doing this in Jest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** Looks like I had some issue in my original response when I merged different files in to a single files I expected it to work as before but **it didn't** so make sure to put  function(s) you want to inject in to separate file(s).

As mentioned earlier, unit test should just test functionality of function it self while mocking dependencies.

I moved functions in to separate files, in one file all functions are defined and in another test.

**enums.js**

```
export const Enums = {
  Signatures: {
    SIGNATURE_1: 1,
    SIGNATURE_2: 2,
    SIGNATURE_3: 3,
    BAD_SIGNATURE: -1
  }
};
```

**convertArrayIntoInt.js**

```
export function convertArrayIntoInt(array) {
  // processing...
  return array.length;
}
```

**getSignature.js**

```
import { convertArrayIntoInt } from "./convertArrayIntoInt";
import { Enums } from "./enums";

export const getSignature = (fileContents, position) => {
  let signature = convertArrayIntoInt(
    fileContents.slice(position, position + 4)
  );

  for (let s in Enums.Signatures) {
    if (signature === parseInt(s, 10)) {
      return signature;
    }
  }

  return signature;
};
```

**tests.spec.js**

```
import { getSignature } from "./getSignature";
import { Enums } from "./enums";
import * as convertArrayIntoIntModule from "./convertArrayIntoInt";

it("Function check", () => {
  // arrange
  const spy = jest.spyOn(convertArrayIntoIntModule, "convertArrayIntoInt");
  spy.mockReturnValue(Enums.Signatures.SIGNATURE_1);

  // act
  const expected = Enums.Signatures.SIGNATURE_1;
  const actual = getSignature([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 1);

  // assert
  expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  expect(actual).toEqual(expected);

  // clean up
  spy.mockRestore();
});
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tdd-algorithms-with-jest-typescript-forked-bg6r4) that I created to test dummy function similar to yours.

Comment: This doesn't appear to actually work work. https://codesandbox.io/s/tdd-algorithms-with-jest-typescript-forked-lei8q - If I mock the return value to an actual signature and expect that actual signature returned, the test fails.

Comment: Here is another sandbox showing that the mocked return is never called https://codesandbox.io/s/tdd-algorithms-with-jest-typescript-forked-movpq

Comment: @Cygnini-ShadowRi5ing updated my response, I merged working code from separate files in to single one and that was the issue on the codesandbox. Thake a look at updated links and example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have heard it right. A unit test should only test a single unit/function. What you can do is, you can make another unit test to check convertArrayIntoInt() function, and for this function, you can set dummy return values for convertArrayIntoInt() in order to verify other logic is working correctly or not.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but with Jest, what's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: tbh I don't have any experience with Jest. But I think this would be helpful https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html

Comment: I'm not sure how to get this to work in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You can spyOn convertArrayIntoInt function and mockReturnValue.
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. If you know how to get this to work, provide example code.